# I'm supposed to do a list inside a class, with a function to add to list or delete but its not working

Tags: python, oop

whats wrong ?

```
class Team:
    lineup=[]
    bench=[]
    def __init__(self,teamName,nation,coach):
        self.teamname=teamName
        self.nation=nation
        self.coach=coach

    def assignLineup(PlayerGK, PlayerDefense, PlayerMiddle, PlayerForward):
        self.lineup = [PlayerGK, PlayerDefense, PlayerMiddle, PlayerForward]

    def addSubstitute(p):
        self.bench.append(p)

    def substitution(inP, outP):
        self.lineup.remove(outP)
        self.bench.append(outP)
        self.lineup.append(inP)
        self.bench.remove(inP)
```

Comment: "It's not working" doesn't give us anything to go on. We need a specific problem or error, with the complete error message if there is an error message (including full stack trace, if there's a stack trace), and we need something we can run that produces the error when run. We don't have any of that here.

Comment: can you provide any examples/what you want to achieve?

Comment: You are missing `self` as the first argument to your methods

Comment: Also, `bench` and `lineup` are shared by all instances of the class. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: i'm a beginner and this site wont let me ask questions us there a way i can contact any of u please

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this :
Create a class Team that has the following:
1. The name.
2. The nationality
3. The coach.
4. The lineup which is a list of 4 players.
5. The bench of substitutes which is a List of players.
6. A constructor to initialize the name, the nationality and the coach. 
7. A function assignLineup(PlayerGK, PlayerDefense, PlayerMiddle,
PlayerForward) that assigns the lineup by the players passed as parameters.

Comment: 8. A function addSubstitute(P) that adds a player P to the bench. 
9. A function substitution(inP, outP) that substitutes the lineup player whose jersey number is outP by the bench player whose jersey number is inP. Note that the outgoing player takes place on the bench. Also, if the outgoing player is the captain then the incoming player becomes the captain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your problem

```py
class Team:
    lineup=[]
    bench=[]
    ...
```

You're not declareing `lineup` nor `bench` as `class variables`. To do that, you need to declare them in `__init__` (the class constructor)

Notice how in `addSubstitute()` it calls `self.bench.append`? It's trying to call the `bench` class variable, but it doesn't exist.

This should work for you

```py
class Team:
    def __init__(self,teamName,nation,coach):
        self.teamname=teamName
        self.nation=nation
        self.coach=coach
        self.lineup = []  # declare lineup class variable
        self.bench = []   # declare bench class variable

    def assignLineup(self, PlayerGK, PlayerDefense, PlayerMiddle, PlayerForward):
        self.lineup = [PlayerGK, PlayerDefense, PlayerMiddle, PlayerForward]

    def addSubstitute(self, p):
        self.bench.append(p)

    def substitution(self, inP, outP):
        self.lineup.remove(outP)
        self.bench.append(outP)
        self.lineup.append(inP)
        self.bench.remove(inP)
```

**Note**: In the future, you should provide more information about the error you are getting. For example, pasting the stacktrace of whatever error you are getting. Also, it is critical for others to know *what your desired end result is*.

Comment: In the functions, I'm getting this error: Unresolved reference 'self'

Comment: thank for for reporting the error. The issue is that your class functions do not include `self` as the first argument. For example `def addSubstitute(p):` should be `def addSubstitute(self, p):` -- I've since updated my answer to include the proper function signatures

Comment: yes it worked thank you. is there a way I DM you please ?

Comment: sadly, I do not believe stackoverflow allows DM'ing users

Comment: i need to ask about this part 
A function SaveLineup() that allows to store the list of players in a text file in the format of the following example.

Comment: maybe on twitter or by email

Comment: Actually, that *is* assigning class variables, but the OP wants *instance* variables

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - indeed, you are correct. Thank you for the correction